# Is Aristotle's fallacy actually a fallacy?

Tags: fallacies, aristotle

In Indian syllabi, students of Physics are told that Aristotle wrongly believed that an external force was required to keep a body in motion. However, based on the little I've read on Aristotelian terms, it seems that when he talked about motion, it was usually in the sense of moving from potentiality to act, in which case he was technically right.

The reason I'm asking this here is because most results on Google seem to be from amateur Indians who don't know Aristotle or just tutoring websites.

Comment: Learning philosophy from Google is like getting married by lottery. *Sometimes* that works out, sure, but seriously...

Comment: Yes, in modern terms, A believed that [motion requires the action of a force](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-natphil/#Moti); example : when we are on a boat, if we stop rowing, after a while the boat cease to move.

Comment: See [Aristotle's Physics: a Physicist's Look by Rovelli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4057) for a sympathetic account. Aristotle mostly dealt with examples of motion in a resistive medium, where his surmise is approximately right. However, since motion in the air was also plain to observe he did not fully think it through. His "explanation" of arrow's motion was mocked already by Philoponus, and medieval authors had to introduce *impetus* to fix it, see [Is Buridan's impetus the same as velocity in Aristotle?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/29777/9148)